# Output from a bash script looping through multiple directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am currently trying to write a script that will loop through multiple directories. The main raw_data directory contains ~150 subdirectories (subj001, subj002,...,subj00n), each of which has several subdirectories.

How can I make sure that the output from the script given bellow will be sent back to the specific subdirectory (e.g. subj0012) the input was taken from, rather than the current directory (raw_data)?

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in ~raw_data/*
do
  tractor -d -r -b preproc RunStages:1 
done
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does `tractor` read its input from the current directory, and write output to that same directory? It does not appear from your example that the current value of `dir` affects how `tractor` works.

Comment: Yes it does. This has been a problem. By far I have been manually specifying the directory in order to deal with this. However, all the scripts using loops I tried have failed. I would really appreciate if you have any suggestions. I apologize if I have not presented the problem clear enough but I am not advanced user of linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the dir you want to save the output to is in `$dir`, right? So, just send the output there via redirection:

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in ~raw_data/* ; do
    tractor -d -r- b preproc RunStages:1 > $dir/output
done
```

You should make sure that what you are processing really is a directory, though.

Comment: The structure and the size of the data complicate the script. I want to send each output to the original subject directory (subj001) rather than the study directory (raw_data).

Answer (score 0):

You can use output of `find` to run a loop and append the output at desired location like this:

```
while read d
do
    echo $d >> ~raw_data/subj0012/output
done < <(find ~raw_data -type d)
```